# Regular expression to retrieve string parts within parentheses separated by commas

Tags: python, regex

I have a String from which I want to take the values within the parenthesis. Then, get the values that are separated from a comma.

Example: x(142,1,23ERWA31)

I would like to get:

- 142
- 1
- 23ERWA31

Is it possible to get everything with one regex?

I have found a method to do so, but it is ugly.

This is how I did it in python:

```
import re
string = "x(142,1,23ERWA31)"
firstResult = re.search("\((.*?)\)", string)
secondResult = re.search("(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))", firstResult.group(0))
finalResult = [x.strip() for x in secondResult.group(0).split(',')]
for i in finalResult:
    print(i)
```

> 142
>
> 1
>
> 23ERWA31

Comment: Why not just split `firstResult.group(0)` by ccomma?

Comment: @anubhava You mean the same way I did with the *finalResult*?

Comment: Yes, possible with PyPi `regex`, but why? Capture the part inside parentheses and split it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for your example string:

```
import re

string = "x(142,1,23ERWA31)"
l = re.findall (r'([^(,)]+)(?!.*\()', string)

print (l)
```

Result: a plain list

```
['142', '1', '23ERWA31']
```

The expression matches a sequence of characters not in `(`,`,`,`)` and – to prevent the first `x` being picked up – may not be *followed* by a `(` anywhere further in the string. This makes it also work if your preamble `x` consists of more than a single character.

`findall` rather than `search` makes sure all items are found, and as a bonus it returns a plain list of the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this a lot simpler. You are running your first Regex but then not taking the result. You want `.group(1) (inside the brackets)`, not `.group(0) (the whole match)`. Once you have that you can just split it on `,`:

```
import re

string = "x(142,1,23ERWA31)"
firstResult = re.search("\((.*?)\)", string)

for e in firstResult.group(1).split(','):
    print(e)
```

Comment: Damn, that's more like it. You just take everything within the parentheses and then separate them with a comma.

Comment: You need to first make sure there is a match before accessing `firstResult.group(1)`. Then, it should probably be `.strip()`ed. Then, `re.split(r'\s*,\s*', firstResult.group(1))` might yield "nicer" results.

Answer (score 1):

A little wonky looking, and also assuming there's always going to be a grouping of 3 values in the parenthesis - but try this regex

```
\((.*?),(.*?),(.*?)\)
```

To extract all the group matches to a single object - your code would then look like

```
import re
string = "x(142,1,23ERWA31)"
firstResult = re.search("\((.*?),(.*?),(.*?)\)", string).groups()
```

You can then call the firstResult object like a list

```
>> print(firstResult[2])
23ERWA31
```